# Multiple threads with multiple alarms in C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, signals

I have a client-server application, running on a threaded server, which requires that each connection from a client create a new thread, the client has to wait x seconds before being served, currently i am using a sleep call in the beginning of each thread function to make this happen, but i would like to use alarms(SIGALARM) how would i go about doign this ?

```
int main()
{
        int sd,connfd,retbind;
        struct sockaddr_in serveraddress,cliaddr;
        socklen_t len;
        pthread_t th1;
        char buf[100];

        sd = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 );
        if( sd < 0 )
        {
                error_exit(SYSTEM_ERROR, "Socket");
        }

        memset( &serveraddress, 0, sizeof(serveraddress) );
        serveraddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
        serveraddress.sin_port = htons(MYPORT);
        serveraddress.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

        retbind=bind(sd,(struct sockaddr*)&serveraddress,sizeof(serveraddress));
        if(-1==retbind)
        {
                error_exit(SYSTEM_ERROR, "Bind failed");
        }

        listen(sd,5);

        printf("-----------------------------------------\n");
        printf("Server running on port number %d\n", MYPORT);
        printf("------------------------------------------\n\n");

        for(;;)
        {
                printf("Waiting for connection...\n");

                len=sizeof(cliaddr);

                connfd=accept(sd,(struct sockaddr*)&cliaddr,&len);
                if (connfd < 0)
                {
                        if (errno == EINTR)
                                printf("Interrupted system call ??");
                        else
                                error_exit(SYSTEM_ERROR, "Connection");
                }

                printf("Connection from %s\n",
                inet_ntop(AF_INET,&cliaddr.sin_addr,buf,sizeof(buf)));

                pthread_create(&th1,NULL,thread_func,(void*)connfd);


        }

}

void* thread_func(void *connfd)
{
        socket_ip buffer;
        int pointer = 0, n;

        pthread_detach(pthread_self());

         sleep(30);

        readWriteFile( (int)connfd, &buffer);

        show_packet(&buffer);

        close((int)connfd);

        pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

for example if a client request is received at 10 secs, 20 secs and 25 sec they should be served at 40 secs, 50 secs and 55 secs.

Help :/

Comment: What is the advantage of using a signal over something that, (presumably), already works OK?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use multiplexing calls like [select](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) or `pselect` or [poll](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll). See also the [select tutorial](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select_tut) man page. And you could use [posix timers](http://linux.die.net/man/3/timer_create)

And many libraries provide you with good event handling like e.g. [libevent](http://libevent.org/), [Glib event loop](http://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/glib/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html) from Gtk etc etc...

Comment: I've seen these functiosn but i dont get how i would go aboutusing them for this function. can you help ?

Comment: Read a good Posix or Unix programming book (e.g. Stevens' http://www.apuebook.com/  etc...), or read carefully the documentation   and study the event handling libraries.